# How would i visualize the set to be able to understand and answer this question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $A$ be the set of all people who have ever lived. For $x, y \in A$, $xRy$
if and only if $x$ and $y$ were born less than one week apart. Determine:

(i) Whether or not the relation $R$ is reflexive;

I understand that $x$ is in relation to $y$ if $x$ and $y$ were born less than one week apart, but how would you mentally visualize this relation to be able to answer the following question, and when answering the question do I answer for when $x$ is in relation to $y$ and when they aren't in relation or just assume that they will always be in relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $xRy$ **iff** $x$ and $y$ were born less than one week apart, we have that $xRx$, for all $x$, because $x$ is born exactly the same day of $x$.

See [Reflexive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation) :

> In mathematics, a *reflexive* relation is a binary relation on a set for which every element is related to itself. In other words, a relation $R$ on a set $A$ is reflexive when $xRx$ holds true for every $x \in A$. Formally, when :
>
> > $∀x \in A, xRx$ holds.

Comment: so how would I declare an answer to the question (i) stated above, what you have written above?

Comment: Do I just assume that for the question xRy always?

Comment: or for the question do I answer ∀x,y∈A,xRy is not reflexive, as ∀x∈A is not equal to y∈A ?

Comment: any update on your answer and my questions would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

When answering the question, you only care about $x,y$ such that $x=y$. Has anybody ever been born more at least a week before or after the day on which s/he was actually  born? It's ridiculous, right?

You can visualize this as a calendar, starting about 100,000 years ago and stretching, oh, let's hope far into the future. Each day of the calendar is filled with the name (/rank/serial-#/DNA-encoding/...) of every person ever born. The cells, and thus the calendar, can be pretty big. Let's say it's a daily calendar, and it's one continuous scroll, no separate pages. Then $x,y$ are born on the same day *iff* they appear in the same cell; they're born a day apart if they appear in adjacent cells; they're born at most two days apart if they appear in the same cell, adjacent cells, or in cells that are two apart; they're born at most three days apart if the distance between the cells they appear in is at most $3$; ... .

Comment: ah i see so would that make the answer to the question not reflexive, as ∀x,y∈A, xRy is not reflexive, as ∀x∈A is not equal to y∈A ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've said all I can. (exasperated)

Comment: You can tell me if my answer is right or wrong, this isnt a maths question I can put in a calculator to see if I'm right... I'm struggling to understand this exactly, and being vague isn't helping

Comment: I have not been at all vague. I've offered as much intuition as I think is possible. I feel that you refuse to focus on the definition of *reflexive* and figure out what it really means. It's very simple. You ask for an explanation, for a way to visualize the relation. I tell you ao good way. In fact two people answer you well, and you come back to us both and say, "So what's the answer?" Frankly it's offensive.

Comment: It's false to say that for for all $x,y\in A$ $x$ is not equal to $y$. Why not actually read the answers, think about them (use the calculator on top of your shoulders), and realize that they've told you what you need.

Comment: Apologies my friend, you are right, it was my understanding of the term reflexive that was the downfall here, I was seeing $x$ and $y$ as _different_ people (elements of the set) so in my thinking i was trying to equate $Jack$ ($x$) to $John$ ($y$), whereas i know now that im just comparing $x$ to all values in A, so $xRx$

Comment: If I may ask a question, would it be true to say that the set relation is not transitive, as $John$ was born less than a week apart from $Jack$ who was born less than a week apart from $James$, does not imply that $John$ was born less than a week away from $James$? Or would it be transitive, as the relation between $John$ and $Jack$ is the same as the relation between $Jack$ and $James$?